# Creating a table using given items

Tags: python

This simply creates a table using the items passed in. I would like to make this function shorter and/or more efficient. What I have seems pretty redundant.

```
def apriori_creator(items, k):
    """Function that creates apriori table using supported candidates"""
    table = []
    the_length = len(items)
    new_k = k-2 # first k-2 items as described in algorithm in book for 'apriori gen'
    for x in range(the_length):
        next = x + 1
        for y in range(next, the_length):
            combined = items[x].union(items[y]) # merge
            l_sub_one = list(items[x])
            l_sub_one.sort()
            l_sub_two = list(items[y])
            l_sub_two.sort()
            first = l_sub_one[:new_k] # getting the first k-2 items of the set
            second = l_sub_two[:new_k]
            if first == second: 
                table.append(combined)
    return table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency, you can take take some things out of the inner loop:

- The computations that depend only on `x` should be in the outer loop.
- The computation of `combined` should be under the `if` where it is used.
- Using `enumerate` and direct iteration instead of `range` is simpler and a little faster.
- `l_sub_one = sorted(items[x])` does the same as these two lines:

  ```
      l_sub_one = list(items[x])
      l_sub_one.sort()
  ```

Revised code:

```
def apriori_creator(items, k):
    """Function that creates apriori table using supported candidates"""
    table = []
    new_k = k-2 # first k-2 items as described in algorithm in book for 'apriori gen'
    for x, item_x in enumerate(items):
        l_sub_one = sorted(item_x)
        first = l_sub_one[:new_k] # getting the first k-2 items of the set
        for item_y in items[x+1:]:
            l_sub_two = sorted(item_y)
            second = l_sub_two[:new_k]
            if first == second: 
                combined = item_x.union(item_y) # merge
                table.append(combined)
    return table
```

---

A further improvement is possible. 
One way to describe what you are doing is that you are generating all different pairs of items that share the same value of `sorted(item)[:new_k]`. Your code does this by considering all possible pairs. A more efficient approach would begin by grouping the items by that value. With the help of a dictionary this only requires one pass over the items. Then you only need to generate pairs withing each group.

Here's again revised code. I'm using `collections.defaultdict` for grouping, and `itertools.combinations` for pairing.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

def apriori_creator(items, k):
    """Function that creates apriori table using supported candidates"""
    new_k = k-2 # first k-2 items as described in algorithm in book for 'apriori gen'
    groups = defaultdict(list)  # group by the first k-2 items of the set
    for item in items:
        l_sub_one = sorted(item)
        key = tuple(l_sub_one[:new_k])
        groups[key].append(item)

    table = []
    for group in groups.values():
        if len(group) > 1:
            for item_x, item_y in combinations(group, 2): # all pairs
                combined = item_x.union(item_y) # merge
                table.append(combined)
    return table
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you expect `items` to be a list of `set`s.  I think you could make use of [a more appropriate data structure](//stackoverflow.com/q/5953205/1157100), such as [`SortedSet`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html).

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet

def apriori_creator(items, k):
    table = []
    items = [SortedSet(item) for item in items]
    for x, item in enumerate(items):
        for later_item in items[x+1:]:
            if item[:k-2] == later_item[:k-2]:
                # Since the first k-2 elements are the same, we should only
                # need to merge the remaining two elements, at most.
                table.append(item.union(later_item[k-2:]))
    return table
```